# Swift - enum inside enum

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I'm trying to present an action menu based off a main and subtype sorting system. But I'm having some issues with enums.

- enum:

  ```
  enum MaterialClassification: CaseIterable {
      enum Main: String, CaseIterable {
          case clay = "Clay"
          case flux = "Flux"
          case all = "All"
      }

      enum Sub {
          enum Clay: String, CaseIterable {
              case kaolin = "Kaolin"
              case ballClay = "Ball Clay"
          }

          enum Flux: String, CaseIterable {
              case flux = "Flux"
          }

          enum All: String, CaseIterable {
              case all = "All"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- variables

  ```
  // Filter:
    var filterClass: MaterialClassification.Main = .all
    var filterSubClass: MaterialClassification.Sub = .all // Not currently working
  ```
- code

  ```
    // Add Material Types:
        for materialClassification in MaterialClassification.Main.allCases {
            let newAction = UIAlertAction(title: materialClassification.rawValue, style: .default) { action -> Void in
                self.filterClass = materialClassification.self
                self.setFilterButtons(first: self.filterClass)
            }
  ```

I have 2 different functions for creating an action sheet. The first works perfectly and uses the loop above to to cycle through all of the cases in MaterialClassification.Main.

My issue is in trying to use the same/similar loop, but to then tap into MaterialClassification.Sub instead of .Main (through the **var filterClass**?) in order to get the proper list of sub settings.

Obviously I could use a switch to hard code it, but that doesn't sound as educational.

Comment: your `MaterialClassification.Sub` has no cases; it just declared some nested enum types, so that's why you can't assign `.all` to it.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply. The question was not how to assign .all to MaterialClassification.Sub.

Comment: @StonedStudio Do you want to make `MaterialClassification.Sub` `CaseIterable`?

Comment: The question isn't clear. You're saying "trying to use the same/similar loop" over `MaterialClassification.Sub`, but what are you looping over exactly?  @StonedStudio

Comment: @RomanPodymov Yes. That way each case's rawValue can be used as in the action sheet. And then when a choice is selected, filterSubClass can be set with: self.filterSubClass = materialClassification.Sub.self